# Fixing a curtain rail to dry wall

Tags: repair, drywall, curtain-rail

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to DIY, so I'm after some advice...

I've recently bought a curtain rail for my living room, and I need to fix it to the wall. However, the wall is not brick -- it is dry wall. I believe this means that there is only a small thickness in the wall, then a gap, and then the outer brick wall. The curtain rail itself comes with two brackets and some screws, but very limited instructions.

My question is: Will my wall be able to support the curtain rail? Or will the dry wall be too thin to ensure the screws have a strong fix? And will I need plastic plugs, or will the screws on their own be fine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need plastic plugs (screws alone in drywall aren't enough), but traditional framing will have wood structure above and a couple inches to the outside of a window opening. If you can keep your brackets close to the edge, you should hit wood.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stud finder (or other method), to locate the framing around the window. Then use long enough screws to go through the brackets, and into the framing.

If you use drywall anchors, the drywall may support the rail. However, if you hang a heavy curtain, or accidentally yank on the curtain. The anchors could pull out of the wall, leaving a mess behind.

Comment: Thanks. But the brackets for the curtain rail can only really go in one position -- otherwise the curtain will be too short/long, or off-centred. So would finding the studs actually help in this case?

Comment: If you don't attach to framing, there's a possibility that the anchors will pull out.